# Django, use South or upgrade to 1.6?

Tags: django, django-south, database-migration

So I started on my first Django app about a month and a half ago. My database is moderately large, and I'm at the point where I need to alter some of my models. My Django version is at 1.5 and I've looked up and researched that South is the de facto standard for migrations at that version, however 1.6 introduced migrations built in, but since it's still fairly new, should I try South or upgrade to 1.6?

Comment: 1.6 does not have migrations built in, 1.7 does. This question is misleading. Source:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/

Answer (score 1):

As Django's current official version is 1.5.4, I'd recommend using South.  In the development version of Django, they're building South into the framework, which should work very similarly.  I expect that once it's released as well, they'll have some way to migrate Django 1.5 + South to Django w/migrations.

You might run into other issues migrating to the beta version of Django, some of which may not be supported.  Also, it appears that the migrations are being [built into 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#a-brief-history) according to the development version documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I would also recommend using South. You'll probably have to run fake migrations if your using an existing database http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#options.

Basically:

```
./manage.py schemamigration app_name --initial
```

Then

```
./manage.py migrate --all --fake 0001
```

Comment: What do you mean an existing database? I've built my database with django.

Comment: If you already have the site up an running then hooking your app up to use South will take an extra step of faking the first migrations (as the tables are already there).

Comment: Well I have my site deployed on Heroku, but I have a local copy of the same database. So can't I run South, make modifications, update my db, push my app onto Heroku, and then dump my local db to my deployed db?

Comment: Yep, I was just trying to point out that you'll need to run the fake migrations to get up and running :) That's a slightly different process then just starting where you'd run `schemamigration app_name --initial` then `migrate app_name` if you were to try that (and your tables already exist) south throws an error. Sorry if I've added a bunch of confusion :D As others have pointed out choosing south is more of an opinion, but it does do a pretty good job. Hope that helps.

Comment: As side note, and something I didn't when I started was south's provision for dependencies [http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dependencies.html](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dependencies.html).